# Lucene: - indexing and finding unique terms

Tags: java, lucene, memory-efficient

I have written a code in lucene, which firsts indexes xml documents, and finds the number of unique terms in the index.

Say there are n number (no.) of unique terms.

I want to generate a matrix of dimensions nXn, where

```
m[i][j] = (co_occurrence value of terms (i, j))/ (occurrence value of term i)
```

co_occurence of terms (i, j) = no. of documents in which ith term and jth terms, both are occurring
occurence of term j is the no. of documents in which the term j is occurring.

My code is working fine.  But its not efficient.  for large no. of files, where no. of terms are more than 2000, its taking more than 10 minutes.

here is my code for finding co_occurence  -

```
int cooccurrence(IndexReader reader, String term_one, String term_two) throws IOException {

    int common_doc_no = 0, finaldocno_one = 0, finaldocno_two = 0;
    int termdocid_one[] = new int[6000];
    int termdocid_two[] = new int[6000];
    int first_docids[] = new int[6000];
    int second_docids[] = new int[6000];
    int k = 0;
    for (java.util.Iterator<String> it = reader.getFieldNames(
            FieldOption.ALL).iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String fieldname = (String) it.next();

        TermDocs t = reader.termDocs(new Term(fieldname, term_one));

        while (t.next()) {

            int x = t.doc();

            if (termdocid_one[x] != 1) {
                finaldocno_one++;
                first_docids[k] = x;
                k++;
            }
            termdocid_one[x] = 1;
        }

    }

    /*
     * System.out.println("value of finaldoc_one - " + finaldocno_one); for
     * (int i = 0; i < finaldocno_one; i++) { System.out.println("" +
     * first_docids[i]); }
     */
    k = 0;
    for (java.util.Iterator<String> it = reader.getFieldNames(
            FieldOption.ALL).iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String fieldname = (String) it.next();

        TermDocs t = reader.termDocs(new Term(fieldname, term_two));

        while (t.next()) {
            int x = t.doc();

            if (termdocid_two[x] != 1) {
                finaldocno_two++;
                second_docids[k] = x;
                k++;
            }
            termdocid_two[x] = 1;
        }

    }
    /*
     * System.out.println("value of finaldoc_two - " + finaldocno_two);
     * 
     * for (int i = 0; i < finaldocno_two; i++) { System.out.println("" +
     * second_docids[i]); }
     */
    int max;
    int search = 0;
    if (finaldocno_one > finaldocno_two) {
        max = finaldocno_one;
        search = 1;
    } else {
        max = finaldocno_two;
        search = 2;
    }

    if (search == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (termdocid_two[first_docids[i]] == 1)
                common_doc_no++;
        }
    } else if (search == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (termdocid_one[second_docids[i]] == 1)
                common_doc_no++;
        }
    }
    return common_doc_no;

}
```

code for calculation of knowledge matrix: -

```
void knowledge_matrix(double matrix[][], IndexReader reader, double avg_matrix[][]) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<String> unique_terms_array = new ArrayList<>();
    int totallength = unique_term_count(reader, unique_terms_array);
    int co_occur_matrix[][] = new int[totallength + 3][totallength + 3];
    double rowsum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= totallength; i++) {
        rowsum = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= totallength; j++) {
            int co_occurence;
            int occurence = docno_single_term(reader,
                    unique_terms_array.get(j - 1));
            if (i > j) {
                co_occurence = co_occur_matrix[i][j];
            } else {
                co_occurence = cooccurrence(reader,
                        unique_terms_array.get(i - 1),
                        unique_terms_array.get(j - 1));
                co_occur_matrix[i][j] = co_occurence;
                co_occur_matrix[j][i] = co_occurence;
            }

            matrix[i][j] = (float) co_occurence / (float) occurence;
            rowsum += matrix[i][j];

            if (i > 1)

            {
                avg_matrix[i - 1][j] = matrix[i - 1][j] - matrix[i - 1][0];
            }
        }
        matrix[i][0] = rowsum / totallength;

    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= totallength; j++) {
        avg_matrix[totallength][j] = matrix[totallength][j]
                - matrix[totallength][0];
    }
}
```

Please anyone suggest me any efficient method to  implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put the find process of term_one and term_two in one `for` loop. And you can use two hashsets to save the docid that you have found. And then use `termOneSet.retainAll(termTwoSet)` to get the doc which have both term_one and term_two.